# Binding to Pig STORE or DUMP output in Python

Tags: python, apache-pig

I am looking for the "right" way to write python code that can do work on outputs of Pig jobs.

Here is my situation. I wrote a Pig script to crunch a large amount of data and output a small set of relations. The amount of output data is small enough to be DUMPed to the console directly. E.g.:

```
grunt> DUMP results
(Control, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
(Treatment1, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
(Treatment2, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
(Treatment3, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
grunt>
```

As next step, I want to do some number crunching on numbers across relations, e.g. computing p-vals for significance of observerd treatment results. I would really like to use Python for this: Pig itself is clearly not intended for that kind of task, and I would prefer to not re-write existing code in Java. So what I would like to do is to bind to outputs of either STORE or DUMP command from python somehow, and go forward with that. My issue is figuring out the best way to go forward. Here are the ways I can see:

1. Use Python to write a UDF that will perform the calculation. I can do this; in fact my Pig script already calls a couple of Python UDFs. However, my impression is that UDFs are intended to work on one relation/line of input at a time, and I need to get data from multiple relations to achieve my goal. I can hack together some kind of state storage within UDF in-between calls, but it does not seem like the right solution.
2. Use embedded Python via Jython in Pig 0.9.1. I had high hopes for this approach, but from the limited documentation I found on the feature, it seems to be intended primarily for controlling job flow (the canonical example being detecting convergence in an interative algorithms), and not for working with outputs directly. Specifically, I see documentation for how to bind to job metadata like whether it succeeded or failed, but not how to bind to outputs. Would love to be proven wrong on this one.
3. Have a Python script invoke Pig and pass it local or HDFS paths of desired output locations, waiting job to finish and then using Python to read in/parse relations from that paths. Seems really hacky.

Is there an obvious option I am missing, or a big gap in my understanding of the above options? Your feedback would be most welcome!

Comment: I don't know how to do this with pig, but yelp's mrjob is exactly what you're asking for on #3 in hadoop streaming.  its probably somehow possible to use pig as well. Google shows a few results of people asking for just this.  Donald miner's example does seem sorta simpler to me though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your frustration from personal experience. #3 is actually a very reasonable approach, however, I suggest something slightly different. Instead, use a bash script wrapper to execute both. This has the nice feature that you won't have to do all the awkward shell calls through python.

Something like:

```
pig mypigscript.pig ...
mkdir /tmp/pigout/
hadoop fs -get output/part* /tmp/pigout/
cat /tmp/pigout/* | python mypostprocessing.py
```

The nice thing about this approach is you can get really fancy with parameters, logging, etc. In production, I typically have all the different phases write to log files, check for phases erroring out, etc.

Just to convince you that this is the right approach-- you don't want that small bit of processing over multiple records in the reducer. This doesn't work if you have multiple reducers and doesn't really give you anything because you aren't using parallelism. I think people tend to try to lump too much of their computation into Hadoop and don't do some of the easy obvious stuff outside.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. I am fully aware of the folly of doing the small-fish processing in Hadoop reducers, instead of pulling out results into a more general computational environment. I had been hoping to find a more reasonable way to interface the two; as you point out #3 is probably the best, although far from ideal. Thank you also for the suggestion of wrapping a shell script around the two - that is a good idea, and will make things simpler and more understandable.